# data only fetched after re-render however useEffect code not run due to only run once when screen mounted

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, react-query

In my react-native project, I have one screen needs to query `data` from backend, then, there are some code using the backend returned `data` should only be run once when the screen mounted. This is what I did (I am using [react-query][1] for data fetching from backend):

```
const MyScreen = ()=> {
   // fetch data from backend or cache, just think this code gets data from backend if you don't know react-query
   const {status, data, error} = useQuery(['get-my-data'], httpClient.fetchData);

   // these code only need to run once when screen mounted, that's why I use useEffect hook.
   useEffect(() => {
      // check data
      console.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
      
      // a function to process data
      const processedData = processeData(data);
      
      return () => {
        console.log('Screen did unmount');
      };
   }, []);

   return (<View>
            {/* I need to show processed data here, but the processedData is scoped in useEffect hook & I need to have the process data function in useEffect since only need it to be run once */}
           </View>)
}
```

My issue:

The code in `useEffect` only run once when the screen is mounted, however at that point the query above returns `data` with value `undefined` until re-render happens, the `data` is then fetched however code inside `useEffect` will never run again though the data is fetched when re-rendered . How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Try to add add `data` to dependencies array (second argument of useEffect) to render your component any time the data object changes. Change `[]` to `[data]`

Comment: The reason why I use `[]` is because when I use `[data]` I get endless re-rendering. Because inside `useEffect` there are code to set/initialize a global state variable the value is parsed from `data`.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing what exactly is httpClient.fetchData, I can only assume it will return a res.json. you should be able to do something like this.

```
   const {status, data, error} = useQuery(['get-my-data'], httpClient.fetchData).then((res)=>{processData(res)});
```

With this, `data` should now become the `processedData` in your example.

Comment: hooks cannot be called inside useEffect.

Comment: didn't realize that useQuery is a 3rd party lib hook. Updated my answer.

Comment: the `then` function is not supported by `useQuery` seems.